# Python Connexion - Response Trimming

Tags: python, flask, swagger, swagger-codegen, connexion

I'm using [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io/) to generate a Python Flask server, I followed the [Connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) document but there's a problem:

I defined the following response in the swagger YAML file:

```
responses:
  '200':
    description: successful operation
    schema:
      type: object
      required:
        - firstname
        - lastname
      properties:
        firstname:
          type: string
        lastname:
          type: string
```

What I expected is to return the following response:

```
{
  "firstname": "Jane",
  "lastname" : "Doe"
}
```

However, the database API returns a much bigger dataset, for example:

```
user=db.get_user_info()
pprint.pprint(user)

{
  "firstname" : "Jane",
  "middlename": "foo",
  "lastname"  : "Doe",
  "age"       : "25",
  "sex"       : "male",
  ...
}
```

To return the response I expected, I have 2 solutions, but neither of them are perfect:

**Solution 1:**

Manually define a smaller dataset, for example:

```
user_response = {
  "firstname" = user["firstname"],
  "lastname"  = user["lastname"]
}

return user_responose
```

But obviously, for each response I have to hard code a *variable*_response, which means I have to maintain the response properties in 2 places (both swagger YAML and the code).

**Solution 2:**

The models are generated by swagger codegen, so I have to access the models and try to get the response properties, for example, the user model probably defined like this:

```
self.swagger_types = {
  'firstname': str,
  'lastname': str,
}
```

This could be easy but in reality the response properties have lots of $ref and there are always $ref inside $ref. I can't find a way to get the all the properties easily.

So my question is, what is the best solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When doing `user=db.get_user_info()`, is there a way to specify a list of fields (e.g. firstname, lastname) you need? (I'm no expert in Python but seems to me a decent ORM should have such feature)

Comment: It's possible, the problem is, I don't know what fields needs to be returned unless I use solution 1(hard code the fields I need, which is duplicated with the content in swagger YAML), or use solution 2(get the fields from the generated model, which seems very hard because of the recursive reference in the fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connexion does not influence in how you can do what you want here. What you could do is to access your Swagger definitions in your handler and then check which fields need to be returned.

About the how to de-ref the JSON objects. You can see [here how Connexion does that](https://github.com/zalando/connexion/blob/master/connexion/operation.py#L227-L304).

Connexion will validate the response of your endpoints if you set the parameter `validate_responses=True` in your `connexion.App#add_api` method call. So don't worry if your schema does not match with the spec, Connexion will throw an exception at runtime. Remember to write tests for your code, so you will get this kind of errors before deploying your app to production.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I've also realized that I have to access Swagger definitions myself. Before that I was trying not to access my Swagger definition because Connexion already done it, I thought I shouldn't to do it twice. But it looks like there's no object provided to get the response schema. For the validation part, I've also noticed it will help validate my schema, so that part is cool. Anyway, thanks again for your explanation!